# How can I set the tab order for multiple controls in XAML

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, xaml, expression-blend-4

Do I have to manually set the TabIndex property of each control on my page, or is there a way I can select multiple controls and get either Expression Blend or Visual Studio to apply the tab index in the order I selected them.

I know this is a feature of other UI tools, but it seems Blend / VS doesn't have this option. If I have a page with many fields that could change position or add a new fields in half way it takes a lot of effort for not much gain to manually update all the tab indexes.

Comment: were you able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Why is the default tab order not sufficient? It's constructed from the ordering of the visual tree. Simply move your XAML around to create a different tab order; set IsTabStop to false to remove that control from the tab order.

Comment: unfortunately not, we have custom controls that wrap others, so I need the containing item to hold the tab focus, not the text box it holds, so the default doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Is default tab order calculated from XAML placement of your objects or compiled visual tree? I'm having same issue where I need to press twice for some objects to get focus.

Comment: The default order is what's listed in XAML or programmatically added to the container.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by setting `IsTabStop="False"` on the container element.